# Custom Dialog Width and Height in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to build a custom dialog in Xamarin as follows. However, I could not able to find a property to set dialog `width` and `height`

```
var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.SetDialogView, null);
var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
dialog.SetView(view);
dialog.SetTitle("Settings");
var dialg = dialog.Create();
layoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
```

Comment: Please as good stackoverflow practice, please mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, kinda tricky (show it and then change the size.), but work:

```
dialg.Show();
dialg.Window.SetLayout(300, 300);
```